# Android webview render text with special characters very slowly

Tags: android, webview

I run into big problem with rendering in android webview.

With long text (for about 150000 characters) contains special characters like this

> sÓ ẻỸ ẤỸẸ ÃèÂ mxuÒ ẳXÒỬx ÃxèẨ ẨiỸy ẳXủ ẨXóÂ, ẨiỸy 17/10/1996. sèÒ
>   ẩxẳẳẢẨttéỔ êẢẨi ẳXVÒ ÂéỮẨ ỔĨẨ wẢẨ ẰÒtiẸ ẳùẨi êèÒ ớXẢéitéỔ, ÃèÂ êèÒ
>   ĂxỠÂ XÒọẨ ÂéỮẨ wxÝté ẩẸứẻ ẨhÃ ẨiẸỐÒ. sèÒ ẩxẳỔ êẢẨi ÂXxẢ, 17-16. Ỗổ êậ
>   ÂXxẢ ÃổÒ ẳxèẳ êỠx. Ỗổ êậ ÂXxẢ ÂẸỸẨ ÃùẢ iÒẫÒ. Ỗổ êậ ÂXxẢ ÂẸỸẨ ÂXóÝ dỜ.
>   sèÒ ẩxẳẳẢẨttéỔ ẳXẽẢ ÂôẨi ÂXjẨi ÃèÂ ÂéóẨ ẨỸẸ ỡ ltỔÂ ớẸẢỔÂ ÂéẸẨi 16 ẨhÃ
>   ẨẢy, ẨXÒỬx ẳgx ÂXủ XÒọẨ ẨẢy ẳủẢ êèÒ êẢẨi Xổẳ ÂÒãx Xổẳ dXÒ êèÒ ẩxẳỔ ẳÓ
>   êẽắẳ ÃùẢ iÒẫÒ ÂXjẨi ẻắÒ ẻgẨ ẳxFÒ ẳùẨi. ặhÃ ẨẢy, ÂXỸẨX ÂƠẳX ẳủẢ Xổ ẻỸ
>   2-8. ẺéẸẨi ÃèÂ ÂéóẨ êỠx, êèÒ ẰtÂéẸÒÂ ăÒẸẨỔ – ÃèÂ êèÒ ẳXVÒ éỠÂ Âọ ẨỮẨ
>   ỔẢx ẨỸy ÃổÒ ẨiẽQÒ ÂXẽQẨi iổÒ ẻỸ “Ấâ ẤổẨi” ÂXẢy ẤỊ “Xy
>   ẤổẨi” – êậ êỐẨX mrÒ êèÒ ẩxẳỔ ẤpÒ ÂẮ ỔF 21-6 ẤỸ 3 ÂxgẨ ỔẢx, êÒỬx
>   êÓ ẻGÝ ẻrÒ ẤpÒ ÂẮ ỔF 27-0. ặiẽQÒ ÝXụ ÂéỐẳX ẳXxyỮẨ Ãụẳ ÂXã ÂXẢẸ ẳủẢ ÃèÂ
>   ÂQ mỐẸ êậ mjÂ êgx ỀùẨi ẳỐÒ ÂỮẨ “ẺXẫÃ ẳXùÒ ẳXĨẨ ÃỸx ẳẢÃ ẳủẢ ẨiẽQÒ
>   kỎ” êã ẨÓÒ ẤỬ ẩxẳỔ. ẹwẲặ ỀỶ êẸỐẨ ẰxẨiy ỔẶ mf ỔẢ ÂXẫÒ Âéẽpẳ dXÒ
>   XIÂ ẨhÃ Ềù âẨi ẤôẢ ÃpÒ êẫÃ ẨXóẨ Ấf ÂéƠ XẾÒ ÂXỐẨi ÊÒỮẨi ẤôẢ éẾÒ.
>
> Ẻxy ẨXÒỮẨ, ẨiẸỸÒ êẽQẨi mÒỮẨ, dXÒ ẰxẨiy êẢẨi ơxẢẨ ỔỐÂ êèÒ mÓẨi ẳủẢ
>   âẨi ÂỶ ÝXĨẨ ẳâẨi Ấf ÂéƠ ẳXẸ XÒọÝ êỠx ÂÒIÝ, ẳÓ ẤẪ ẨXẽ ẳxFÒ ẳùẨi ÃGÂ
>   ÂéQÒ êậ ẳXÒIx ĂxyỮẨ ÃỸẨ ÃĨy. ỰẨi dXâẨi ẳẽQÒ. ỰẨi dXâẨi mẢẸ iÒQ êã ẻè
>   ẳẫÃ Ăúẳ ÂéẸẨi ỔxFÂ ÂéóẨ êỠx. ặXẽẨi ẳÓ iỊ êÓ Ăẫy éẢ ÂéỮẨ ỔĨẨ, êÒỬx ÃỸ
>   âẨi êậ ẻỸÃ ẤÒọẳ ẳXhÃ ẳXẮ êã XẽpẨi êIẨ ÂéẸẨi ẨXÒỬx ẨhÃ. ạXÒ ÂÒIẨi ẳẽQÒ
>   ẨXrẸ ẳủẢ 50.000 dXỐẨ iÒẫ êèÒ mrẨ XẽpẨi ẤỬ ẺẸẨy ẰxẨiy, âẨi êậ ÂXỠy ÃèÂ
>   êÒỬx ÃỸ dXâẨi ẢÒ ÂXỠy. ỰẨi ÂXỠy êẽắẳ mÁẨi ẳX@Ẩi ẤỬ XÒọx ơxẫ ẳủẢ dI
>   XẸrẳX âẨi êậ êGÂ éẢ.

For example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Many text contain special characters like above    blablabla

```
</html>
```

It took about >= 11 seconds without including fonts and >=5 s including font.

In the same case I load a text with the same length, but with normally font available in android system. So it took about <=500 mls.

Is it caused by the special characters in the text and android take time for those.

This is the code to load content to webview

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, origintext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Also remove cache from webview.

Comment: if it fix only text content than why using webview?

Comment: No, this is actually an hml file contains some special characters

Comment: If there is static html file you can try with put in asset and than load it

Comment: it's a text html, I tried loading from file, too slow

Comment: 150K is a bit. What about splitting into smaller hunks (separate files)?

Comment: No, I just want to load that long text, not splitting!